# Parameter defaults using other parameters in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to do something like this in Python?

```
def func(list, l = len(list)):
    print list, l
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually how it is done

```
def func(list, l = None):
    if l is None:
        l = len(list)
    print list, l
```

As a side note, avoid using built-in type/function names as your variable names(like `list` here)

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as you can get:

```
def func(list, l = None):
    print list, l if l is not None else len(l)
```

The default parameters are evaluated when the function is first encountered.  Since `list` is not known at that point, this is not what you want.